# Special characters don't work in bashrc

Tags: bash, prompt, hostname

I've been looking to a tutorial on how to customize my terminal. 
When I try to customize the PS1 into something like

```
PS1="\u@\h \W -> "
export PS1;
```

After I source the file in the terminal, instead of getting the **username@host directory** I get

```
\u@\h \W ->
```

What I have so far in my .bash_profile and .bashrc files is:

**.bash_profile**

```
if [ -s ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc;
fi
```

**.bashrc**

```
PS1="\u@\h \W -> "
export PS1;
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: play with \ or quotes

Comment: What output do you get for `echo $0`?

Comment: @muru in the terminal?

Comment: @Ryk wherever it is that you're seeing `\u@\h \W ->`

Comment: The output is -zsh

Comment: You're running zsh, not bash. Try putting it in `~/.zsrhc` instead.

Comment: I've put the same code in the .zshrc file and then sourced it ```source .zshrc``` but I go the same ans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What output do you get for `echo $0` ?
>
> The output is `-zsh`

Which seems to mean you're running Zsh, not Bash. Zsh doesn't support Bash's prompt expansions, but has a system of its own. See: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html

Try to put something like this in `.zshrc`:

```
PS1='%n@%M %~ -> '
```

You could verify which login shell you have by peeking at `/etc/passwd`, or running `getent passwd $USER` (should work on Linuxes). The last field is the shell.

If you want to run Bash as your login shell, `chsh -s /bin/bash` should work to change that.

Comment: it works, thanks. what happens to the bash files (where I put my code firstly)? Do they override or since I use .zsh does the .zshrc have higher priority?

Comment: @Ryk, yeah, that is a bit curious. If your login shell indeed is Zsh, like it looks to be, then it seems odd for the Bash-specific files to be read at all. Since you export `PS1` it might perhaps get inherited to your zsh process, but since a non-interactive Bash clears it, that doesn't happen too often. I'm guessing blindly here anyway.

Comment: It might be a misguided attempt at "migrating users to `zsh`" through simply sourcing the user's `bash`-related files from the corresponding `zsh` initialization files.

Comment: @Kusalananda, yep, that could be one...

Comment: @Ryk, you may want to check all your init files, see: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html and https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html

Comment: Thanks for the insight